# Recursive method to return value only from the last recursive call

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, recursion

I have a recursive method which processes items that are retrieved from a stream. However, I want the method to return the stream.NextPosition only when there are no more items to process. However, since this is a recursive method, the compiler complains that not all code paths return a value.  Makes sense because the recursive calls aren't returning anything. How do I approach this problem, where I am only interested in the return value of the last call.

```
public void Process()
{
   int position = ProcessStream(0)  
}

//recursive method 
public string ProcessStream(int streamPosition)
{
   var stream = GetStream(streamPosition);

   if (stream.Items.count == 0)
     return stream.NextPosition;

   foreach(var item in stream.Items)
   {
      ProcessItem(item);
   }

   ProcessStream(stream.NextPosition)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must `return ProcessStream(stream.NextPosition)` at the end of your function.

```
public string ProcessStream(int streamPosition)
{
    var stream = GetStream(streamPosition);

    if (stream.Items.count == 0)
        return stream.NextPosition;

    foreach(var item in stream.Items) {
        ProcessItem(item);
    }

    return ProcessStream(stream.NextPosition)
}
```

Comment: So move the if statement to the bottom?

Comment: No, add a `return` to the last line.

Comment: @Prabhu No, you can leave everything as is, just put the `return` keyword in front of the recursive call.

Comment: @hatchet Was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood.  So just add the return statement in front of the ProcessStream call at the end...

Comment: This makes the code compile but logically this is not correct.

Comment: @zsong - for the benefit of the OP, maybe giving a reason why it's not correct would be helpful.